# Genymotion on Ubuntu - Won't start virtual device

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, genymotion

When I start a virtual device it just hangs with the message "Starting virtual device"


[image]

The steps I have taken:

1. Installed virtual box via apt
2. Downloaded Genymotion from the website executed the .bin file and installed it
3. Ran it and downloaded a virtual device and started it

Basically, I haven't changed any of the settings but I tried starting it multiple times and it doesn't work.

Comment: Got the same problem : installed official Oracle VirtualBox 5.1 and Extension Pack. Ubuntu 16.10 64 bits. ATI Radeon R3.

Comment: @loloof64 Are you running avast antivirus software on your device and if so can you try to shut it down and then try it again

Comment: Thanks @Glacier11. In fact the problem had been resolved in https://askubuntu.com/a/891519/97744. So I just needed to delete an installed file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/891519/97744) from stackoverflow, which was what solved my problem.